# How to extend a MVC Core 2 webapp with additional MVC Core 2 applications

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

We need to be able to extend an existing MVC Core 2 application (Main) with additional MVC Core 2 applications (Modules) similar to the example shown at https://www.atlascode.com/blog/self-contained-ui-running-one-asp-net-core-mvc-site-inside-another/.

However, we want to create the app in such a way that additional apps can be added without needing to redeploy the Main application.

Is there a way to do this? We've tried to find other resources regarding this topic, but haven't had much luck.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the following 2 projects, They helped me allot in this area.

- [NopCommerce](https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/tree/develop)
- [ExtCore](https://github.com/ExtCore/ExtCore)

NopCommerce works well in this respect, the main application can import everything including Scripts and styles from the added application. They also have a good data structure.

Hope that helps you out some moving forward.

Comment: Thanks! We'll take a look and let you know how it goes.